# Exclude files in Xcode - Swift 4

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Hi guys I have to exclude some mp3 files from a project, I tried with 
`mySong = mySong.replacingOccurrences(of: "Mr. Blue Sky", with: "")` but in my table view there is always a blank clickable space that play the .mp3. Under You can find the full code. This code is based on the fetching of informations through the groups and URL.
This file have to be excluded only in this Swift. Please help me.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class viewHappy: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView2: UITableView!


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return songs.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = songs[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        do
        {
            let audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: songs[indexPath.row], ofType: ".mp3")
            try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath!) as URL)
            audioPlayer.play()
            thisSong = indexPath.row
            audioStuffed = true
        }
        catch
        {
            print ("ERROR")
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        gettingSongNames()
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }


    //FUNCTION THAT GETS THE NAME OF THE SONGS
    func gettingSongNames()
    {
        let folderURL = URL(fileURLWithPath:Bundle.main.resourcePath!)

        do
        {
            let happyPath = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: folderURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .skipsHiddenFiles)

            //loop through the found urls
            for happySong in happyPath
            {
                var mySong = happySong.absoluteString

                if mySong.contains(".mp3")
                {
                    let findString = mySong.components(separatedBy: "/")
                    mySong = findString[findString.count-1]
                    mySong = mySong.replacingOccurrences(of: "%20", with: " ")
                    mySong = mySong.replacingOccurrences(of: ".mp3", with: "")

                    songs.append(mySong)
                    print (findString)
                }

            }

            myTableView2.reloadData()
        }
        catch
        {
            print ("ERROR")
        }
        var session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        do
        {
            try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)

        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You really need to give us a little more context here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a list of songs, say…

```
struct Song {
    let title: String
    let mp3: MP3
}

let songs = [Song(title: "Mr. Blue Sky", mp3: mp3_1),
             Song(title: "Evil Woman", mp3: mp3_2),
             Song(title: "10538 Overture", mp3: mp3_3)]
```

then you can remove a song from your list using `filter`…

```
let filteredSongs = songs.filter { $0.title != "Mr. Blue Sky" }
```

Then in your table view delegate, return `filteredSongs.count` as your `numberOfRows`

Comment: I'll try this! Thanks!